# Turbogears nostests results in OperationalError when using SQLAlchemy-FullText-Search

Tags: sqlalchemy, nosetests, turbogears2, operationalerror

I recently installed **SQLAlchemy-FullText-Search** dependency in (https://github.com/mengzhuo/sqlalchemy-fulltext-search), but since that I get unexpected results. When I run

```
nosetests -v
```

An `OperationalError: (OperationalError) near "(": syntax error u'ALTER TABLE opportunity ADD FULLTEXT (title, content, requirements)' ()` comes out.

I'm defining **fulltext_columns**:

```
__fulltext_columns__ = ('title', 'content', 'requirements')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like SQLAlchemy-FullText-Search does only work on MySQL databases - but the default test suite of a TurboGears 2 webapp is using an SQLite in-memory database, so that might be the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to use an MySQL in-memory database instead?

Comment: You can change the sqlalchemy.url in test.ini to use your MySQL server - but this will probably not be as performing as SQLite in-memory.

Comment: How could I test same full text search functionality with SQLite? Would it be worth to implement only for testing? Thanks.